# Should I use factors or characters for identifiers in large data.table datasets?

Tags: r, data.table, r-factor

**Problem.** When I work with large datasets (millions of rows) in `R`, I use the `data.table` package. Recently, I have had to work with string identifiers (such as "AEREOBCOIRE045451O34") that have low cardinality in the sense of `unique(x)/length(x)`. There is a question of which type is appropriate for storing such identifiers: `character` or `factor`?

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34865113/11838549), Matt Dowle explains that operations in `data.table` have been optimized for `character`. After reading it, my take-away was that I should always use `character` identifiers. However

1. [This comment by @MichaelChirico](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18323344/11838549) suggests that this reasoning is outdated.
2. There can be a significant memory gain in using `factors` (about 20% in the reproducible example below).

**Question.**  Given the reproducible example below, there are significant gains in terms of memory from switching to `factor`-type identifiers. Is there a trade-off between memory and speed here? Specifically, since Matt Dowle explains that some operations are optimized for `characters`, what would be the costs of using `factors` instead?

**Additional context.** The issue of `characters` vs. `factors` has been discussed a lot on Stack Overflow (see for example [here (1)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34865113/11838549), [here (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18323344/11838549) or [here (3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691050/data-table-still-converts-strings-to-factors); there are many others). The advice provided has evolved quite a bit over time, and, as of today, it's not clear from reading previous answers what the best practice is.

**Reproducible example for memory usage.**

```
library(data.table)
library(pryr)
set.seed(1234)

N <- 1e7
vec_id <- stringi::stri_rand_strings(100, 40)
id_lowcard <- sample(vec_id, size = N, replace = TRUE)
v1 <- runif(N)
v2 <- rnorm(N)

A <- data.table(id_lowcard,
                v1,
                v2)
B <- data.table(as.factor(id_lowcard),
                v1,
                v2)

cat("Memory gain: ", round((object_size(A) / object_size(B) - 1) * 100), "%")
```

Comment: This question is more suitable at [data.table GitHub](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues)

Comment: @zx8754 Thanks for the comment, I will consider asking it there. Given that this issue has been discussed a lot on Stack Overflow in the past, I think that others could benefit from answers. I will edit the question to provide more context on this.

Comment: I have edited the question substantially. I think that this should make the question much less "opnion-based" and that it could be re-opened. I would be happy to address additional concerns if any should be raised.

Comment: I'm reviewing as "Leave closed" because the question seems to lack clarity, specifically "conflict with character-based optimization" is unclear. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/29431659)

Comment: @IanCampbell I have edited the overall question to make it clearer. The part that you found unclear referred to this (linked) answer by Matt Dowle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34862856/are-factors-stored-more-efficiently-in-data-table-than-characters/34865113#34865113